# multiband antenna for RF

Tags: rf, antenna

I'd like to make a small chip using either the Texas Instruments CC1101 or the Nordic nrf9e5 that provides a range of different frequencies. This is mostly meant to be a tool for playing around at my local hackspace and doesn't need to have perfect signal characteristics, just "good enough". I've been looking at lots of different multiband antenna and the [Abracon ACA-105](http://www.abracon.com/patchantenna/ACA-105-T.pdf) seems to do everything I want it to do. I realize this isn't what's recommended in the datasheet but could I in theory attach a cc1101 to this (with the proper caps, resistors, and inductors) and have it send from those 4 different bands? If so, it seems like a dream come true, but I'm afraid it's too good to be true. Any suggestions or resources on multiband antanna for RF much appreciated.

Comment: The ACA-105-T datasheet omits the important information on how to connect and feed it. The antenna is just a ceramic rod with a coil around it. It could be used on any one of the frequencies by selecting the correct tuning components, but not all at once.

Comment: How small must your antenna be? What frequencies do you want to radiate? Is efficiency important for your tests? Antennas are generally a half wavelength long, so roughly 35 cm for the bands you mention, is that ok?

Comment: Those RF chips are so so cheap, why not just make several different transmitters, each with its own tuned antenna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. With a suitable matching network (which may be tricky since matching networks are typically themselves somewhat narrowband) you can use that antenna and a frequency-agile transceiver such as the CC1101/CC1110 at any of the frequency ranges quoted.

An alternative is to use a broadband antenna such as the [log-periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-periodic_antenna) which you could [construct yourself](https://archive.org/details/TheArrlAntennaBook) or print onto the PCB.  That would cover a wide range of frequencies, e.g. 200 MHz to 2 GHz, unlike the antenna you linked which works well only within several narrow frequency ranges.  Such selectivity is often useful for suppressing out-of-band noise in an application like a cell phone (for which the Abracon was likely designed) but isn't as useful for your professed use of "playing around" ;)  The Ettus software-defined radios [ship with](http://www.ettus.com/product/category/Antennas) log periodic antennas for exactly that reason.